# Convert DBObject to a POJO using MongoDB Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, dbobject

MongoDB seems to return BSON/JSON objects.

I thought that surely you'd be able to retrieve values as Strings, ints etc. which can then be saved as POJO.

I have a DBObject (instantiated as a BasicDBObject) as a result of iterating over a list ... (cur.next()).

Is the only way (other than using some sort of persistence framework) to get the data into a POJO to use a JSON serlialiser/deserialiser?

My method looks like this:

```
public List<User> findByEmail(String email){
         DBCollection userColl;
         try {
            userColl = Dao.getDB().getCollection("users"); } catch (UnknownHostException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } catch (MongoException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
            DBCursor cur = userColl.find();
            List<User> usersWithMatchEmail = new ArrayList<User>();

            while(cur.hasNext()) {
               // this is where I want to convert cur.next() into a <User> POJO
               usersWithMatchEmail.add(cur.next());
            }
        return null;
    }
```

EDIT: It's pretty obvious, just do something like this.

Comment: Stupid me, you can just call get(<key>) on a DBObject and get the value. I'll post the code.

Comment: I just want to point out the most recent answer, where a driver-native solution is proposed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49926224/503900

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a few java libs that can help you with it:

- Morhpia - http://code.google.com/p/morphia/
- Spring Data for MongoDB - http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb

Comment: Thanks, for now I'm trying to learn the Java API but will use one of those eventually.

Comment: +1 for spring-data-mongodb, its fantastic.  Has annotations to specify document ID, field names, doc references; be aware there is no support for cascading saves: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-references

Comment: @AndrewB can Spring data mongodb be used in an EJB project? And is it a wise thing to do? Since rest of my project has no dependency over Spring whatsoever!

Answer (score 49):

Let Spring do the heavy lifting with the stuff it already has built for this...

The real trick is: mongoTemplate.getConverter().read(Foo.class, obj);

For example, when using a DBCursor -

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
    DBObject obj = cursor.next(); 
    Foo foo = mongoTemplate.getConverter().read(Foo.class, obj);  
    returnList.add(foo); 
}
```

http://revelfire.com/spring-data-mongodb-convert-from-raw-query-dbobject/

Comment: Thank you so much for this. For a quick start, the maven dependency is: org.springframework.data / spring-data-mongodb / 1.3.2.RELEASE

Comment: You deserve a cookie :D

Comment: nice work chris mathias. But i also need reverse of this process. i.e converting java object to BasicDbObject. any help? Thanks

Comment: The question was not about SPRING

Answer (score 6):

Though a late answer , someone might find this useful.

I use GSON to convert from `BasicDBObject` to my own POJO which is `TinyBlogDBObject`

```
TinyBlogDBObject obj = convertJSONToPojo(cursor.next().toString());
```

---

```
private static TinyBlogDBObject convertJSONToPojo(String json){

    Type type = new TypeToken< TinyBlogDBObject >(){}.getType();

    return new Gson().fromJson(json, type);

}
```

Comment: this doesn't work because of the id returned in the form {"_id":{"$oid":xxxx} and gson complains. You need to manually convert it to a string or replace the value in a jsonobject.

Comment: Or you can supply your own _id values as strings in the first place, and avoid problems like that.

Answer (score 5):

**1. Provide MongoDatabase bean with proper CodecRegistry**

```
@Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/dbname");

    ConnectionPoolSettings connectionPoolSettings = ConnectionPoolSettings.builder()
            .minSize(2)
            .maxSize(20)
            .maxWaitQueueSize(100)
            .maxConnectionIdleTime(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .maxConnectionLifeTime(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    SocketSettings socketSettings = SocketSettings.builder()
            .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
            .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder -> builder.applySettings(connectionPoolSettings))
            .applyToSocketSettings(builder -> builder.applySettings(socketSettings))
            .build();

    return MongoClients.create(clientSettings);
}

@Bean 
public MongoDatabase mongoDatabase(MongoClient mongoClient) {
    CodecRegistry defaultCodecRegistry = MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry();
    CodecRegistry fromProvider = CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build());
    CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(defaultCodecRegistry, fromProvider);
    return mongoClient.getDatabase("dbname").withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);
}
```

**2. Annotate POJOS**

```
public class ProductEntity {

    @BsonProperty("name") public final String name;
    @BsonProperty("description") public final String description;
    @BsonProperty("thumb") public final ThumbEntity thumbEntity;

    @BsonCreator
    public ProductEntity(
            @BsonProperty("name") String name,
            @BsonProperty("description") String description,
            @BsonProperty("thumb") ThumbEntity thumbEntity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.thumbEntity = thumbEntity;
    }
}

public class ThumbEntity {

    @BsonProperty("width") public final Integer width;
    @BsonProperty("height") public final Integer height;
    @BsonProperty("url") public final String url;

    @BsonCreator
    public ThumbEntity(
            @BsonProperty("width") Integer width,
            @BsonProperty("height") Integer height,
            @BsonProperty("url") String url) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

**3. Query mongoDB and obtain POJOS**

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("product");
Document query = new Document();
List<ProductEntity> products = collection.find(query, ProductEntity.class).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Please check my answer in other post 
[POJO to org.bson.Document and Vice Versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320825/pojo-to-org-bson-document-and-vice-versa/49918311#49918311)

Comment: How do you handle date/time classes in case of using POJOs?

Comment: You do not have to use date/time mongo data type at all. Instead you can use long datatype where you can save current timestamp. There is also second probably even better option that you can get a date from ObjectId. I always use one of these two options (long or object id), I never use date/time mongo data type

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) library provided by Google. Here is the [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) of it. There are many other api that you can use to convert json into pojo like jettision api,etc.