# Using Java can one store BSON documents in MongoDB directly bypassing the DBObject API?

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongo-java

I think [Jongo](http://jongo.org/) does it by using the Jackson pipeline to efficiently convert a POJO into the respective BSON, thus bypassing any intermediaries, like `DBObject`. However, it depends on Jackson 2.x (now FasterXML) and I am not in a position to upgrade from Jackson 1.9.x, so it seems I cannot use Jongo.

So, I am using the standard Java mongo driver, which requires me to map a POJO into the respective DBObject (see [Efficient POJO mapping to/from Java Mongo DBObject using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789471/efficient-pojo-mapping-to-from-java-mongo-dbobject-using-jackson)), which I suppose is marshalled to a BSON buffer by the driver at some point before being sent to the Mongo server process.

My question is this - can I prepare the BSON buffer myself and just hand it over to the driver?

Comment: You can do something like `DBObject dbo = new LazyWriteableDBObject(baos.toByteArray(), new LazyBSONCallback());` where `baos` is a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. The rest is part of the mongodb Java driver api.

Comment: Are you looking for java-mongodb ORM alternative?

Comment: I surely need one. The question whether to do it by smartly plumbing somewhere the Jackson JSON pipeline or take another library. Had I not had the no-upgrade limitation I would have surely gone with Jongo. As it is I am more looking for an efficient way to utilize the Jackson JSON object mapper.

Comment: @assylias - can you show how can one take a BSON buffer and insert it into a Mongo DB collection without creating an intermediary DBObject instance?