# DBObject to Map in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to put the result from MongoDB in Map. My code is

```
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("template");
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(allQuery, removeIdProjection); 
DBObject resultElement = null;
resultElement = cursor.next();
```

and the result Json is:

> { "GraphLabel" : "Volume Of Work Orders" , "XaxisLabel" : "2012" ,
>   "YaxisLabel" : "volume(k)" , "ShowLegend" : "FALSE" , "query" :
>   "select sd.season_id,sd.season, count(fsf.defect_type_id) from
>   m2m.season_dim sd ,m2m.field_service_fact fsf where fsf.season_id =
>   sd.season_id group by sd.season_id"}

Need to put the values with MAP or POJO .. Can somebody help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684223/convert-dbobject-to-a-pojo-using-mongodb-java-driver

Comment: I dnt want to use Jackson...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `DBObject` has a `toMap()` method which transforms it into map

Answer (score 1):

Below Code would do:

```
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("template");
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(allQuery, removeIdProjection); 
Document doc = cursor.next(); // Which is already a Map compatible object

Map <String, Object> mDoc = doc;
```