# Save json date field with date format on MongoDB

Tags: java, json, mongodb, date

I am using Mongo DB and on saveData method I'm trying to save the data object
on Mongo DB. First I am converting the data object in JSON format and after I save
the object on Mongo DB. But there's a problem. My Class Object has a atribute initialDate with
Date Type, but when this code saves the object on Mongo the initialDate atribute is saved as a string,
but I need that it be saved in date format. Someone can help me?

```
public void saveData(ClassObject data) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
    String dataJson = jsonObject.toString();
    DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(dataJson);
    DBCollection table = mongoDB.getCollection(data
            .getModel().getProjectName());
    table.insert(dbObject);
}
```

Here the ClassObject

```
Class ClassObject {

private int value;
private ParentModel model;  
private Date initialDate;

...
//here get and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `date` is getting converted into string while doing `toString` on `jsonObject`. You need to convert it back to `date` type after you do `JSON.parse` -

```
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(dataJson);

// TODO: Convert dbObject's initialDate property back to date type here

DBCollection table = mongoDB.getCollection(data
        .getModel().getProjectName());
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting the object to JSON will convert the date to a string as JSON does not have a date type.

You can manually set the `initialDate` in the `dbObject` like so

```
 dbObject.put("initialDate", data.getInitialDate());
```

and this should save the date as a date.

A better solution would be to use a library to map between the java classes and json, as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7684293/965322